# Solve differential equation $y''-2y'+3y=\sin x$ using invers operator method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

> $$y''-2y'+3y=\sin x$$

$s^2-2s+3=0$
$s=1 \pm i\sqrt {2}$ 
uisng operator $(D^2-2D+3)y_1=\sin x$ 
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= \frac{1}{D^2-2D+3}\sin x \\
&= \Im\left(\frac{1}{D^2-2D+3} e^{ix}\right) \\
&= \Im \left(\frac{1}{i^2-2i+3}e^{ix}\right) \\
&= \Im \left(\frac{1}{2-2i}e^{ix}\right) && (***) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Im \left( \frac{1+i}{1+1} e^{ix}\right) && (***)\\
& = \frac{1}{4} \Im \left((1+i)(\cos x+i \sin x)\right) && (***) \\
& = \dots
\end{aligned}
i tried to solve problem using differential operator, but i dont understand what im means here, and also the formula too. i dont understand the star part, can someone explain what is this? is this relate to complex number? and does anyone know useful link about this material? and also i tried to solve using undetermined coef or variation of parameter, but compare to this it really takes lots of time.

2. and for differential operator:L(D) ->L'(D) so how to differentiate a differential operator?
$(D-1)(D-2)^3 => (D-2)^2(4D-5)$ can someone give me hint thanks

Comment: @mryoumath yes thankyou for the edit, sorry for typo!

Answer (score 0):

The starred part consists in basic algebraic manipulations of complex numbers, with $i^2 = -1$ and $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$. Indeed,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{i^2 -2i + 3} & = \frac{1}{2 -2i}\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - i} \frac{1+i}{1+i} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1 + i}{2} \, .
\end{aligned}
Now, multiplying by $e^{ix}$ and taking the imaginary part gives the equations of the OP.

Comment: thankyou !!after watched some tutorial, i know that $i^2= -1$ $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ , but there is some unclear part, $ \frac{1}{4} \Im \left((1+i)(\cos x+i \sin x)\right)$, if i multiply the bracket , i got $\frac{1}{4} \Im \left((cos x+i sin + i cos x+ i^2 sin x)\right) $ how can i reduce this to $= \frac{1}{4} (cos x+sin x) $ ?

Comment: oh ok thankyou so much!!!! if you dont mind can i ask how to differentiate differential operator? such as this $:L(D) ->L'(D) ,,(D−1)(D−2)^3=>**(D−2)^2(4D−5)**$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look this equation is to do the following:

$$(D^2-2D+3)y=\sin(x) \implies (D-1+i\sqrt{2})(D-1-i\sqrt{2})y=\sin(x)$$

Now, substitute $w=(D-1-i\sqrt{2})y$ to obtain

$$(D-1+i\sqrt{2})w=\sin(x)$$

This is a linear first order ODE, which can be easily solved by the closed formula for the first order equation. After having obtained this solution you just have to solve

$$w=(D-1-i\sqrt{2})y$$

by using the general formula for the first order linear ODE.

Comment: thanks i find this method really good, is this applicable to all nonhomogeneous differential equation? because the operator method really require lots of formula in each case, and i tried using this method but end up got $\int \frac{d}{dx}e^{xi+\sqrt2 ix}.w= \int sinx.e^{xi+\sqrt 2 ix}$  is this true? the integration part really takes lots of time though and ended up got result $- (\sqrt 2 +1)^2 (sinx+cosx)$ , i know this is wrong..

Comment: This method is always applicable, sometimes you can also use it for partial differential equations. But the integration part is really a little bit annoying :D.

Comment: ok thankyou so much!,  if you dont mind can i ask how to differentiate differential operator like this $L(D) ->L'(D),,,,** (D−1)(D−2)^3=>(D−2)^2(4D−5)** $ didnt understand the star part.

Comment: You should rather ask this as a different question. Maybe other users are also interested in this question. But you should better define what you mean by $L'(D)$ is it $D[L(D)]$?

Comment: maybe, i think it means differentiate the D operator(?). btw which method you prefer to solve differential equation? i find undetermined coefficient and variation parameter really takes lots of time.

Comment: I prefer the ansatz of the right-hand side. If I fail at finding the right ansatz I use the variation of parameters.

Comment: ansatz is the approach that you explained to me?

Comment: No ansatz means that you look at the inhomogeneous part and use something similar as a candidate for the particular solution.

Comment: annihilator method?

Comment: @fiksx See the [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters), in particular the examples.